# element.click() is not emulating the click

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, click, undefined

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button:nth-child(2)').click()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="Dialog ui-dialog-type-message" style="min-width: 300px;"><header><h1 class="dialog-title">Pile Nouveaux éléments pleine</h1></header><div class="dialog-body"><p class="dialog-msg">Vous ne pouvez pas acheter cet élément car vous avez 5 éléments ou plus dans votre pile d'éléments non attribués.</p><div class="ut-button-group"><button class=""><span class="btn-text">Annuler</span><span class="btn-subtext"></span></button><button class=""><span class="btn-text">M'y emmener</span><span class="btn-subtext"></span></button></div></div></section>
```

I'm making a chrome extension and i'm looking to click on the following button :

```
<button class=""><span class="btn-text">M'y emmener</span><span class="btn-subtext"></span></button>
```

On the console with query selector i've got the element :

```
document.querySelectorAll('button:nth-child(2)')[4]
```

It is the right button, every thing is good so far but when i add .click() after the element like so, the element doesn't get clicked either:

```
document.querySelectorAll('button:nth-child(2)')[4].click()
```

How can i get this to click on my button ?

Comment: Try checking `document.querySelectorAll('button:nth-child(2)')[4].click` in console. If it is a function, then the click seems to get called but as it might not be returning anything, so it is giving undefined in the console.

Comment: Are you getting an error message saying the function is undefined, or is that just the return value? `click()` doesn't return anything, so that's the expected value.

Comment: @Nikhil Goyal so whitout parentheses, it tells me that the function .click should be witten  .click()  so i assume that it is a function.

Comment: @Barmar yes i know it could be the expected value but it is actually not even clicking on the targeted element

Comment: @Taplar it returns "5", but i'm specifying in my code that i target the [4] already so it shouldn't be a problem, sould it ?

Comment: @Taplar yes but then why isn't it clicking the button ?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: @Barmar i've added one in the question

Comment: There's no JavaScript in the snippet, what is it supposed to do when I run it?

Comment: @Barmar it is supose to click on the button but i get error saying .click() isn't a function but it is a fonction

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` returns a NodeList, you need to index it with `[0]`. Or use `querySelector()`.